# Type-system combining type-states and typed effects?

Tags: reference-request, type-theory

Has anyone succeeded in implementing or designing a type-system that combines both type-state (linear types) and effect types (e.g. [Koka](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/koka/))?

Comment: [Kitten](https://github.com/evincarofautumn/kitten) has some linear typing (still being figured out) as well as an effect system based on Koka’s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edwin Brady has done some work in that area using dependent types in IDRIS. Take a look at his work, in particular [Programming and Reasoning with Algebraic Effects and Dependent Types](https://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/drafts/effects.pdf) and [Resource-dependent Algebraic Effects](https://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/drafts/dep-eff.pdf).

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer! Could you give at least a very brief summary of what the linked preprints contain? That way, your answer would be more self-contained. A few sentences would be fine.

Comment: Dependent types are very heavy to use. I was hoping for a system more like Rust + Koka.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of work on types for $\pi$-calculus does this. See e.g. (1) for a unified system. Sequential languages can be embedded into $\pi$-calculus, so this work also applies to sequential languages.

(1) [A Uniform Type Structure for Secure Information Flow](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/research/technicalreports/2002/DTR02-13.pdf), K Honda and N Yoshida.